# Can I combine phonegap and native Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am a beginner in Android. I want to combine phone gap and native java android. I want to use sqlitedatabase from assets and copy to android data/data/packagename/databases with phonegap. Can I do that? Please help with example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as combining native Java and PhoneGap, what you are looking to do is develop a plugin:

[Is it possible to interacte between native iphone app and PhoneGap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426209/is-it-possible-to-interacte-between-native-iphone-app-and-phonegap-app/7494501#7494501)

As for the sqlite database, PhoneGap has a File() API for doing these kinds of things:

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileEntry

(see copyTo and moveTo).