# Is it possible to interacte between native iphone app and PhoneGap app?

Tags: cordova

I am developing an iPhone application using the PhoneGap Framework. Here I have to integrate a third party native library into my application. Can you please guide me as to whether it is possible, and if so how can i proceed?

Thanks in Advance,
Sri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what third party library you are trying to integrate with, but in general it's absolutely possible.

What you will need is a plugin to connect the two. Here is the PhoneGap docs on creating plugins:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins

If you need some examples of plugins already written, have a look at the phone gap-plugin repo on GitHub:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Hiedi Utley also has some helpful tutorials around writing plugins:

http://hiediutley.com/

Hope that helps...